# table(subset()) Error in R

Tags: r, subset

I have a climate df that looks like...

```
ID     NAME   DATE   TYPE   VALUE
13943  HARLI  1207   TMIN   50.00
13943  HARLI  1208   TMAX   68.71
13943  HARLI  1015   PRCP   0.02
13258  DFW    1207   TMIN   50.00
13258  DFW    921    TMAX   80.21
13258  DFW    801    TMIN   50.00
13555  WACO   131    PRCP   0
```

I am trying to make sure each station NAME (ID) has a certain number of records for each df. For example, I want DFW to have at least 6900 records in the df else I don't want those records in the new df.

The below code appears to work fine when my types just had TMAX and TMIN in the VALUE column, however, I have since added more data.

```
CombinedFifteenYearsTemp <- CombinedFifteenYears[CombinedFifteenYears$ID
                                %in% names(which(table(CombinedFifteenYears$ID) >= 6900)),]
```

I have included PRCP (and wind data), but I don't want the >= to take into consideration these values. I still only want the stations with >=6900 data points for TYPES that have TMAX and TMIN values. So I thought I could subset the data within the names(which(table())) function, like this...

```
CombinedFifteenYearsTemp <- CombinedFifteenYears[CombinedFifteenYears$ID
                              %in% names(which(table(subset(CombinedFifteenYears,
                              grepl(("TMAX|TMIN"), CombinedFifteenYears$TYPE))) >= 6900)),]
```

However, I get a error stating,

```
Error in table(subset(CombinedFifteenYears, grepl(("TMAX|TMIN"), 
CombinedFifteenYears$TYPE))) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements
```

Is there a function other than table() that can count? FYI, I am very new to R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I changed the `6900` to something that would work with your example. And I made up the "WIND" type but you can add whatever you like there to exclude row from being counted.

```
df <- read.table(text="ID     NAME   DATE   TYPE   VALUE
13943  HARLI  1207   TMIN   50.00
                 13943  HARLI  1208   TMAX   68.71
                 13943  HARLI  1015   PRCP   0.02
                 13258  DFW    1207   TMIN   50.00
                 13258  DFW    921    TMAX   80.21
                 13258  DFW    801    TMIN   50.00
                 13555  WACO   131    PRCP   0", header=T)

toKeep <- table(df$NAME[!df$TYPE %in% c("PRCP", "WIND")]) > 2

df2 <- df[ df$NAME %in% names(toKeep)[toKeep], ]
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I wanted. I guess this n00blet needs to learn more about the table() function.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to recreate your data:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(13943L, 13943L, 13943L, 13258L, 13258L, 
13258L, 13555L), NAME = c("HARLI", "HARLI", "HARLI", "DFW", "DFW", 
"DFW", "WACO"), DATE = c(1207L, 1208L, 1015L, 1207L, 921L, 801L, 
131L), TYPE = c("TMIN", "TMAX", "PRCP", "TMIN", "TMAX", "TMIN", 
"PRCP"), VALUE = c(50, 68.71, 0.02, 50, 80.21, 50, 0)), .Names = c("ID", 
"NAME", "DATE", "TYPE", "VALUE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

This may be a way to accomplish what you want, which you can mod depending on your criteria:

```
require(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(NAME) %>% 
       mutate(n = n()) %>% 
       filter(n>= 6700 & TYPE %in% c("TMIN", "TMAX") | !(TYPE %in% c("TMIN", "TMAX")))
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I needed to do this without dplyr, but I'm sure someone else will find this useful.